# In 有一只小鸟真可怜，它在树枝上冷得发抖 why is 有 at the start?

Tags: translation, grammar, sentence-structure

So I am studying this children´s story, and I can´t find a proper grammar explanation.

> 有一只小鸟真可怜，它在树枝上冷得发抖。

So here I assume 有 indicates the bird´s existence, however in every explanation about 有 grammar I could find they would structure the sentence so that 有 would come after the place and before the subject. (Time/place) + 有 + (subject).

I couldn´t find any grammar that explained this particular kind of compound sentence, nor any other possible explanation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So here I assume 有 indicates the bird‘s existence

Correct. 有 is frequently used as the equivalent of "**there is**" in English. The typical construction is

> place + 有 + noun
>
> Example: 我家里 (place) 有 (existence) 很多椅子 (subject) -> There's many chairs in my house

Then you can also **omit the place** to express just generic existence, as in your sentence:

> 有一只小鸟真可怜 (nowhere in particular) there's a little bird which is really pitiful

This construction can be productively used in story-telling, where the exact location of the subject is not very relevant. Same as in English.

If you add a time complement instead of a location, you get the classical story introduction:

> 很久以前有一只小鸡~ once upon a time (nowhere in particular) there was a small chicken...

Comment: 有一只小鸟真可怜，(there's a little bird which is really pitiful),  有一只很可怜的小鸟 (there's a pitiful /poor little bird )

Comment: You are right, I updated my translation!

Answer (score 2):

> So here I assume 有 indicates the bird´s existence, however in every explanation about 有 grammar I could find they would structure the sentence so that 有 would come after the place and before the subject. (Time/place) + 有 + (subject).

This is probably a textbook sentence pattern, and sure, we can rewrite this sentence into that pattern.

> 在樹枝上「有」一隻真可憐的小鳥。它冷得發抖。

> *Up on the tree branches, **there is** a poor little bird. It's shivering from the cold.*

Rather than follow textbook patterns, what if we wanted to say

> ***There is** a poor little bird, who is up on the tree branches, shivering from the cold.*

Then we would use the sentence you've provided.